# Empty directory when running phpunit with code coverage on a laravel 4.2 projecct

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, laravel-4.2

I am trying to set up phpunit to show the code coverage of my project. I have followed the example found on google and basically have the following set up:

composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.*",
    "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4.0.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.9"
},
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./report/" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="false" 
             lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

When I run all tests on the homestead VM

`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

the tests run but no code coverage is generated to the "report" directory. It remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: found on google -> just link *that* example as google changes things and you don't have shared the search term (and country, IP, Android Version, Your google history and what not is your whole file (life) online which would make that google result obvious). Apart from that (really just link it), it looks like that you didn't add the output of the phpunit run to the question. (1/2)

Comment: On a first shot I would guess that you don't have xdebug enabled and so. no code coverage is given. This is output as "error" however not flagged as an error (perhaps a too much common mistake so not treated as such) and therefore no code-coverage report is generated. Normally this is as simple as enabling xdebug within your `php.ini` so that code-coverage information can be gathered and reported on.

Answer (score 0):

It just occured to me that there is a fatal error that happened while running. After fixing this the code coverage report was generated.